# Send-MailMessage cmdlet runs as I set it as a variable

Tags: powershell, variable-assignment

I am trying to set up Send-MailMessage as a variable.  Once I input in Powershell it automatically sends an email.  My syntax:

```
$EmailTo = "To"
$EmailFrom = "From"
$EmailSmtp = "smtp"
$EmailComputer = "$Env:Computername"
$EmailSubject = "Warning! $Emailcomputer had errors!"
$EmailCopyWarning = Send-MailMessage -to $Emailto -from $Emailfrom -subject $Emailsubject -smtpserver $Emailsmtp -body $CopyFalse
$EmailSvcWarning = Send-MailMessage -to $Emailto -from $Emailfrom -subject $Emailsubject -smtpserver $Emailsmtp -body $CCMExecNoSvc
```

All the variables set above display properly in my code, however when I try to set the variables for $emailcopywarning and $emailsvcwarning they immediately send me an email.  My intent is to only send emails if there are errors.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you want them declared as functions, not variables.

Comment: In that case you need to check for errors and only then call `Send-MailMessage`. Assigning `Send-MailMessage ...` to a variable means you run the cmdlet and assign whatever it returns to the variable.

Comment: There is a ton more going on with this script (not given) which all works.  It's just this part I am having difficulty getting set up.  I have some if statements which check things which triggers whether or not a machine can access the UNC and also if a said service is missing.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function SendCopyWarning {Send-MailMessage -to $Emailto -from $Emailfrom -subject $Emailsubject -smtpserver $Emailsmtp -body $CopyFalse}

If (test-path yada){do this} else {do this; SendCopyWarning}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "save" a particular piece of PowerShell code as a variable to execute later, you need to create a `scriptblock`.

```
$EmailCopyWarning = [scriptblock]::Create("Send-MailMessage -to $Emailto -from $Emailfrom -subject $Emailsubject -smtpserver $Emailsmtp -body $CopyFalse");
```

Then to execute it:

```
$EmailCopyWarning.Invoke();
```

But this isn't *really* what you ought to be doing. Write your error-detection code, and if an error is detected, just send the email. Or call a function you've defined to send it, if your intent is to modularize the script.

Comment: Thanks alroc, it gets assigned, however it returns:

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> $EmailSvcWarning.Invoke()
Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "A positional parameter
cannot be found that accepts argument 'BRT-1142916920'."
At line:1 char:1
+ $EmailSvcWarning.Invoke()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingException

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Here is what I did:  function SendCopyWarning {Send-MailMessage -to $Emailto -from $Emailfrom -subject $Emailsubject -smtpserver $Emailsmtp -body $CopyFalse}...  Then I did an If (test-path yada){do this} else {do this; SendCopyWarning}

Comment: Without seeing the values that you're setting in those variables, it's impossible to say. It's probably interpreting that string as a parameter name; you may have to escape the hyphen or other characters.

Comment: That's okay. I got it to do what I needed it to do.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If you don't show how you solved the problem, how can anyone learn from your experience?

Comment: Thanks everybody. Here is what I did: function SendCopyWarning {Send-MailMessage -to $Emailto -from $Emailfrom -subject $Emailsubject -smtpserver $Emailsmtp -body $CopyFalse}... Then I did an If (test-path yada){do this} else {do this; SendCopyWarning}